# Binding Background from other class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I've got following folder structure in my problem:

```
- Themes                   // folder
  - ThemeManager.cs        // self explaining
  - ITheme.cs              // theme interface
  - Light.cs               // typeof ITheme
```

**ThemeManager.cs:**

```
public static class ThemeManager
{
    public static ITheme Theme { get; set; } = new Light();
}
```

**ITheme.cs:**

```
//using System.Windows.Media
public interface ITheme
{
    string Color { get; set; }
    Brush Color2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Light.cs:**

```
//using System.Windows.Media
class Light : ITheme
{
    public string Color { get; set; } = "#FF00FF00";
    public Brush Color2 { get; set; } = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Lime);
}
```

All three files are in the namespace `MyProject.Themes`.

I use the following code for binding the `Background` property in my `XAML`

```
xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:MyProject.Themes.ThemeManager.Theme"
```

but both

```
Background="{Binding theme:Color}"
Background="{Binding theme:Color2}"
```

make the Background transparent due to no result from the binding.

What am I doing wrong? How can I correctly bind the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xmlns means XML-namespace. It is for namespace. So it supposed to be xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:MyProject.Themes". Also, it is a static property, you cannot bind it the same way as non-static.

In your case, it is

```
Background="{Binding Color, Source={x:Static theme:ThemeManager.Theme}}"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is about UWP (judging by the tag), and the UWP flavor of XAML doesn't support `x:Static`. (Your comment is valid for the full WPF, though.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to make your XAML compile as is -- the compiler doesn't like the binding. Be that as it may, static binding is not the strongest point of the UWP flavor of XAML; I'm not aware of any way to do *exactly* what you want.

One approach is to add a (non-static) property to your code-behind...

```
public string ThemeBackground => ThemeManager.Theme.Color;
```

...and bind to that:

```
Background="{x:Bind ThemeBackground}"
```

If you want to use `Binding` rather than `x:Bind`for some reason, add the property to your data context type.